# How do I get brightness working on a Lenovo IdeaPad Yoga?

Tags: brightness, lenovo, touchscreen

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Yoga. It's been working flawlessly with Windows 8 - 9 hour battery life, awesome touchscreen, 4-second boot times.

So obviously I wanted to try Ubuntu 12.10. Well, I downloaded it and installed it - but I couldn't change the brightness!

These hotkeys work in Windows but not in Ubuntu - and none of the solutions others have proposed in other similar questions with Lenovo laptops have worked.

How can I make my brightness hotkeys work?

Comment: Please tell us which solutions did you try.

Comment: I found an answer! It shall be posted in 6 hours, as new users can't post answers for 8 hours after the questions's been asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## FOR 12.10

Okay, I found an answer in [this](http://www.techjail.net/solved-brightness-problem-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin.html) page.

This solved my brightness problems permanently:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

You will find this line in the new opened window:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save and close the window and type this in the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

## FOR 13.04

1. Add the acpi_backlight=vendor to your grub default command line
2. Run the update-grub command
3. blacklist the ideapad_laptop by adding "blacklist ideapad_laptop" to your /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file.
4. Reboot

Comment: I had precisely this problem on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon under Ubuntu 13.04 and the solution solved it.

Comment: Now, on my T430 in Ubuntu 13.04, brightness gets adjusted properly but the brightness level indicator doesn't show the correct value. Anyway...

Comment: The **FOR 13.04** steps also helped me with making the touchpad of my Yoga 11s work directly after boot, [not only after a standy-resume detour](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2237259) under Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 2):

I have another solution:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=\"!Windows 2012\""
```

and

```
sudo update-grub
```

fixed it for me.

Comment: Huh, I'll try this when I update to 13.04. Thanks!

Comment: This worked well for me on my ThinkPad T430, and fits in with the bug discussion on the kernel change which caused it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for my Lenovo G480:

1. **sudo nano /etc/default/grub**
2. Change the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash" into:

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"`
3. sudo `update-grub`
4. Restart your Linux

This fix should work for another Lenovo models.