# Ubuntu 13.04 64bit. Brightness doesn't work on Lenovo Yoga 13

Tags: 13.04, intel-graphics, brightness

There is solution for [12.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262003/brightness-not-working-on-lenovo), but it doesn't work for 13.04.(Build from 28February)

Any idea what is wrong with 13.04 version and how to fix it?

Additional info:
In /sys/class/backlight/ I have: ideapad and intel_backlight, no signs of acpi_video0

Comment: 13.04 is not fully baked yet. Questions about future versions are off topic.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Ubuntu - as per the FAQ, alpha/beta issues are off-topic.  You can receive help as per this Q&A - http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do