# Error from sudo update-grub

Tags: grub2

I've installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a Lenovo yoga 13. In order to make the backlight work with the keys I've been following some instructions of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262003/brightness-not-working-on-lenovo) (link edited)

The process I followed was this:

1) sudo gedit /etc/default/grub   (generates errors, I think they are irrelevant - have checked in vim the edit worked)

2) sudo update-grub

3) blacklisted the ideapad_laptop by adding "blacklist ideapad_laptop" to  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file

Step 2)
generates error: */usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 27: /etc/default/grub: want: not found*

**Answers from the comments**

- cat /etc/default/grub does show contents of the file
- fgrep want /etc/default/grub gives: # Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
- sudo cat /etc/default/grub also shows contents of the file

**Update**

The grub error from step 2 occurs whenever I try to install anything. I have previously tried to run the command sudo apt-get install grub-pc - which also generates this error. I'm worried I've upset the balance of my computer's universe...

Comment: Does cat /etc/default/grub show the content of that grub-file?

Comment: Please attach the output of `fgrep want /etc/default/grub` to your question.

Comment: Which of them? There are 4 answers.

Comment: perhaps newbish of me ?: sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub - or - sudo apt-get install  --reinstall grub2 ? ( I wonder why to do update-grub for backlight ? - there is command xbacklight in terminal and for this after adjusted with this command the backlight only reboot is necessary - but not update-grub ? )

Comment: The output from the fgrep command is:# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux and cat /etc/default/grub does show the content

Comment: @Braiam the solution is this one:
    Add the acpi_backlight=vendor to your GRUB_DEFAULT command line
    Run the sudo update-grub command
    blacklist the ideapad_laptop by adding blacklist ideapad_laptop to your /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file.
    Reboot

Comment: Any help very gratefully received !

Comment: Please edit your question and add the info. Is hard to read it in comments (these are comments), also instead try `sudo cat /etc/default/grub`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so that was me being an idiot

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
```

was missing the quote mark off the end of it - must have made a mistake while editing the file. All sorted now, and the back light is working from the keys.

thanks @braiam for your help.